# VS22 C++ executable compiled in v143 works despite redistributable being out of date

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

This will be one of the rare occurrences where someone is asking "why does my program work?", not "why doesn't it?"

We recently moved our C++ executables to the VS22 v143 platform toolset. We are still running C++17 though. Our deployment process packages the most recent redistributable VC143_redist.x64.exe, and VC143_redist.x86.exe. (v14.32.31332.0).

We fully expected that the installation process would have triggered the updated redistributable to execute, but it did not. Stranger still, the executables seem to work fine. The test team has confirmed that they are running with C++ 2010 10.0.30319 and C++ 2015-2019 14.22.27821.0 (x86 and x64 for both).

So my question is: how is the executable working? Is there more than just the compiler version at play here?

Comment: Has some other Microsoft or external package already installed the redist or a more up-to-date one ?  You can check in `Control Panel > Program and Features` and scroll the list for _"Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable..."_  - my computer has 9 of them installed

Comment: I'm not aware of anything, but i'd also expect it to show up in the Add or Remove Programs list in Windows.

Comment: The visual studio runtime libraries haven't changed since VS 2015 and are included in most versions of windows, no need to install redistributables

Comment: You could check the registry to see if it has already been installed.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-visual-cpp-files?view=msvc-170

Comment: @Eljay - I'm checking that now.

Comment: @AlanBirtles - that's interesting. My memory was that the executables were pretty finnicky about not having the associated redistributable.

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170, it does say you need a newer redist than the version you built with but I guess there is some leeway or the redist has been silently updated by windows update

Comment: There is more than one way to get the DLLs copied, it doesn't require using the redist installer.  Could be that these machines had a program installed whose installer got the job done, it is not complicated.  Check the properties of vcruntime140.dll and msvcp140.dll to double-check.